# My internet speed is 100 Mbps but my download speed is only 250 kbps Why?

Tags: internet, download

I live in Denmark in the city of Fredensborg, my internet is living its own life, sometimes it has a download speed of 250 Kbps and sometimes it's 750 Kbps, it doesn't matter if I turn all my pcs and iphones off, it doesn't change my internet speed at all.

Speedtest.net says that i have a download speed of 2.5 bits per sec. im using ADSL

Comment: How are you measuring your download speed? What kind of Internet connection do you have? (DSL? Cable? Satellite?) Why do you think your Internet speed is 100Mbps? That's much more likely to be your LAN speed than your Internet speed. What speed does your ISP advertise? What speed do you pay for?

Comment: im using ADSL. how do i paste a picture?

Comment: If you don't even know what kind of Internet connection you have, how could you know its speed is 100 Mbps?! Are you assuming your computer somehow knows the speed of your Internet connection? (The speed of your LAN connection is not the speed of your Internet connection.)

Comment: to truly stress test your line, download http or ftp large files from several different sources... then you will see your true internet speed. but I think you need to dig into your ISP information to see what you actually are paying for.. and unless you pay a lot, it is most likely "best effort" anyway

Comment: oh yeah my foult my lan is 100Mbps

Comment: Well then you have your answer.

Answer (score 4):

100 Mbps is the maximum speed your [LAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network) can support.
Your internet speed is 250 Kbps ( or max 750 kbps).
Regarding internet speed, you can test on websites like [speedtest.net](http://speedtest.net)

Do remember that LAN and internet speed are two different things.
Following links may be helpful :

- [Link 1](http://www.windowsbbs.com/networking-hardware-software/67978-lan-speed-internet-speed-clarification.html)
- [Link 2](http://tehparadox.com/forum/f28/internet-lan-speed-explained-140871/)
- [Link 3](http://www.cctvforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=26168)

Answer (score 1):

The Internet speed also depends on server speed. If you downloading from the server that is shared among multiple users on the web. and the speed will be decreased for no of users increased..

For example. Torrent download speed depends on no of peers it has. here peers act as servers

Answer (score 0):

Well i predict that you are talking about the speed that is shown in the notification area when you are connected with network. Its actually the maximum speed your LAN can support. Further you need to specify what kind of connection you are using. What Internet Tariff plan is it.

You may check your download speed on www.speedcheck.net and other contributors have already cleared many doubts.