# leased line broadband speedup problems

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, broadband, ipsec

i recently upgrade my broadband speed,i was using 1mbps connection that time i get only 125kbps file download speed from everywhere.now i'm using 1mbps leased line. which means i should get 1:1 connection mean 1mbps file or whatever download speed.but this time i get 145kbps file download speed. what should i do?i ask the provider he told me to check the speed in oklaa, i did but in oklaa show me 1mbps speed surfing and download speed, so y can't i get the same speed while i download a file. what to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My internet speed is 100 Mbps but my download speed is only 250 kbps Why?](http://superuser.com/questions/789550/my-internet-speed-is-100-mbps-but-my-download-speed-is-only-250-kbps-why)

Answer (score 0):

First you should check the unit of bandwidth and download rate.

It is very likely your bandwidth unit is mega **bits** while your download unit is kilo **bytes**

Note:
8 kilobits is 1 kilobyte

A 1 Mbps (Mega **bit** per second) connection can sustain *approximately* 128kBps (kilo **bytes** per second).

Make sure that your program is using the same units (bits/bytes) as your connection.

Comment: 1mbps bandwith and 1mbps download both are same

Comment: Anyone is not B  ... are you using download manager for test bandwidht speed? What is you do2nload manager?

Comment: This appears to be a comment not an answer to the question.  Its not clear the reason, you submitted two separate answers, instead of submitting a single quality answer.